# How to print an array from js to an ejs template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, ejs

I'm developing a kind of database-website where you can search people profiles.

I'm trying to print data from a database query but I get: [object Object].

Relevant code:

index.js

```
router.get('/profile/:name', function(req, res){

  db.query("SELECT name FROM people where name='Jack'",function(err,names){

    console.log(names);

    res.render('template', {person: names});
  });

  
});
```

template.ejs

```
<h1>Profile of <%= person %></h1>
```

With the console.log I'm getting what I expected:

```
[ RowDataPacket { name: 'Jack' } ]
```

How can I print only the name "Jack" in <=%person%>?

Comment: The template can only display primitives like string and number.  It can't directly display an object.  So, you need to add to your template exactly which properties of your object you can to display and how you want those different properties formatted in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template can only display things like string and number that can directly be converted to a string with their `.toString()` method (since strings are what has to go into HTML).  It can't directly display an object.

When you try to display an object, it calls `.toString()` on it and gets `"[object Object]"` so that's why you see what you see.

So, you need to add to your template exactly which properties of your object you want to display and how you want those different properties formatted in the HTML.  Refer to the properties themselves in the template.  I don't know exactly what form the data is that you're passing, but if it's an array, then you will have to refer to an array index or create an iterative loop in your template to display all the names in the array.

If you only want the first name from the array and the array is just a plain array of name strings (not an array of objects), you could change from this:

```
res.render('template', {person: names});
```

to this:

```
res.render('template', {person: names[0]});
```

And, that would then render that first name in the list with:

```
<h1>Profile of <%= person.name %></h1>
```

Comment: The db.query result is: [object Object] -> { name: 'Jack' }. I want to print only the second part -> Jack. I tried using loops or refering properties but it didn't work.

Comment: @Desesperado - Well, your question shows this `[ RowDataPacket { name: 'Jack' } ]` which is an array of one object so you'd have to use array syntax and then `.name` on the first item in the array.

Comment: But how do I select only the .name on an array from a db.query?

Comment: @Desesperado - See what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: I had already tried that and it's not working. It prints {"name": "Jack"} on the website using <%- JSON.stringify(person) %>

Comment: Well, you've never shared what's actually in your array.  It looks like it's an array of objects, not an array of names so you would use `<h1>Profile of <%= person.name %></h1>` with the previous code I suggested.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your help!